# Can we select and section point cloud in autodesk forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have to develop a tool with forge with below tasks

1. We should show large point cloud from the local hard disk
2. We should be able to select the points
3. We should be able to section / clip the point cloud

Please let me if we do the above tasks with autodesk forge

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Forge Viewer does not have a built-in support for rendering large scale point clouds. These are some of the options you might want to consider, but I don't think there's any solution that checks all the boxes for you:

### Option 1

Insert points into the scene as `THREE.PointCloud` via the [Scene Builder](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/scene-builder/) extension:

```js
function generatePointCloud() {
    const GridWidth = 1000;
    const GridHeight = 1000;
    const PointsCount = GridWidth * GridHeight;
    const PointSize = 0.1;
    const positions = new Float32Array(PointsCount * 3);
    const colors = new Float32Array(PointsCount * 3);
    let i = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < GridWidth; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < GridHeight; y++) {
            const u = x / GridWidth, v = y / GridHeight;
            positions[3 * i] = (u - 0.5) * 100;
            positions[3 * i + 1] = (v - 0.5) * 100;
            positions[3 * i + 2] = 0.0;
            colors[3 * i] = u;
            colors[3 * i + 1] = v;
            colors[3 * i + 2] = 0.0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
    geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    geometry.isPoints = true; // This flag is important! It will force Forge Viewer to render the geometry as gl.POINTS

    const material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({ size: PointSize, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
    return new THREE.PointCloud(geometry, material);
}

// ...

const sceneBuilder = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
const modelBuilder = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
    conserveMemory: false,
    modelNameOverride: 'My Point Cloud'
});
const points = generatePointCloud();
points.dbId = 12345;
modelBuilder.addMesh(points);
```

This way the point cloud object will behave as any other Forge model - it will be highlighted on hover, selected on click, and it can also be sectioned. Unfortunately, the `THREE.PointCloud` object keeps all the points in memory, so this approach isn't suitable for large scale point clouds.

### Option 2

Load large scale point clouds into Forge Viewer using Potree: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo.

This way you will be able to stream large scale point clouds into the scene, but in this case selection and/or sectioning won't be available. You'd have to implement that functionality on the Potree object yourself.